# Замена значения в строке PHP

Tags: php

Вот у меня есть строка:

```
$data = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tss</title>
</head>
<body>

<comment>text</comment>

</body>
</html>';
```

Мне нужно чтобы заместо text в теге comment было example. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: регулярки в помощь.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = str_replace("text", "example", $data)
```

Comment: Мне нужно изменить значение в comment, оно может быть любым

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте свой шаблонизатор.

Файл index.php:

```
<?php

echo renderTemplate('layout.php', [
    'comment' => 'example'
]);

function renderTemplate($template, $vars = [])
{
    ob_start();
    extract($vars);
    include $template;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Файл layout.php (шаблон):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tss</title>
</head>
<body>

<comment><?= $comment ?></comment>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
$str = '<comment>text</comment>';
$repl = 'значение для замены';

$str = preg_replace('~(<comment>).+?(</comment>)~', '$1' . $repl . '$2', $str);

echo $str;
```